# How to repair CUPS need urgent help

Tags: printing

I messed up my CUPS files, and I need to reinstall, but I don't know how to do it. It's very urgent,I need printer for my work. Please help!

I tried to do sudo apt install cups, but it replied that the cups is already the latest versiona and doesn't need to install.

Someone please help me.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain a bit more clearly what you mean by "I messed up my CUPS files".  CUPS is made up of many packages, and with a clearer explanation we can guide you toward the correct packages to reinstall.

Comment: The correct way to reinstall is `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cups`. But depending on what you "messed up", this may not be the solution. We need more information.

Comment: I managed to save myself, I found this http://www.polarhome.com:783/doc/cups/help/ref-cups-files-conf.html description of the file I messed up and returned it to the way it was. Uf!

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I changed the cups-files.conf file, more specifically hte SystemGroup entry in an attempt to try and get access to the CUPS interface in the web browser.

Comment: I was following the instructions here: http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/utility.html, section 7.2 but I cannot get allowed to make any changes. I would like to be able to see the ink levels and such.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt-get purge cups
```

to remove all install config files and then install cups again.